# Como remover encabezado en importe de csv hacia tabla sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, csv

Tengo que importar un archivo csv a una tabla en sql. La importacion me funciona bien pero quiero saltarme la primera linea la cual es el encabezado.

He tratado varias formas pero no me resulta.

Aqui esta mi codigo.

Muchas gracias

```
string csvPath = @"C:\temp\Users.csv";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] {
new DataColumn("id", typeof(string)),
new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)),
new DataColumn("email",typeof(string))
});

string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
{
    //row.Replace(",", "");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
        {
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
            i++;


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para leer las lineas del archivo podrias usar

```
string[] csvData = File.ReadAllLines(csvPath);
var lines = csvData.Skip(1);

foreach (string line in lines){
  //codigo
}
```

al usar el `Skip()` no salteas la cantidad de linea que indiques

[Enumerable.Skip](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Acabo de probarlo, y me funciono muy bien. muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias soluciones para este tema. Si siempre va a venir con encabezado, puedes implementar un contador para que valides en el if que ese registro no lo agregue. Ejemplo **contador**:

```
string csvPath = @"C:\temp\Users.csv";
int contador = 0;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] {
new DataColumn("id", typeof(string)),
new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)),
new DataColumn("email",typeof(string))
});

string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
{
//row.Replace(",", "");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row) && contador != 0)
{
    dt.Rows.Add();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
    {
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
        i++;


    }
}
contador++;
}
```